# How to get minimax algorithm to return an actual move?

Tags: python, algorithm, artificial-intelligence, minimax

I'm currently trying to implement the minimax algorithm for tic tac toe but I am unsure how to find out how to make a move after you get the min/max of all game_states. I know that you should look at which path has the greatest number of wins but I don't know where to proceed from here.

```
def minimax(game_state):
    if game_state.available_moves():
        return evaluate(game_state)
    else:
        return max_play(game_state)

def evaluate(game_state):
    if game_state.has_won(game_state.next_player):
        return 1
    elif game_state.has_won(game_state.opponent()):
        return -1
    else:
        return 0

def min_play(game_state):
    if game_state.available_moves() == []:
        return evaluate(game_state) 
    else:
        moves = game_state.available_moves()
        best_score = -1
        for move in moves:
            clone = game_state.make_move(move)
            score = max_play(clone)
            if score < best_score:
                best_move = move
                best_score = score
        return best_score

def max_play(game_state):
    if game_state.available_moves() == []:
        return evaluate(game_state) 
    else:
        moves = game_state.available_moves()
        best_score = 1
        for move in moves:
            clone = game_state.make_move(move)
            score = min_play(clone)
            if score > best_score:
                best_move = move
                best_score = score
        return best_score
```

Comment: As you evaluate states, hold on to the best evaluated state so far. When you have either run out of time/gone as far down the tree as you wanted/evaluated the entire search tree, follow the state you've held on to, visiting its parent, its parent's parent, etc. until you reach a node that has no parent. The move that got you there is your next move.

Comment: Actually now that I think about it, minimax does not sound like an exiting algorithm for the tictactoe, because the best plays always result in a draw.

Answer (score 2):

Really simple at the top level - all you need to remember is the best move at the current search depth, and if you evaluate the depth fully then set the best of all to the best of that depth; and try evaluate again with deeper tree. BTW, Greatest number of wins does not matter, a win is a win.

Pseudoish code for the case:

```
bestest_move = None
try:
    for depth in range(1, max_depth):
        best_score = float('-inf')
        for move in possible_moves:
            score = evaluate(move)
            if score > best_score:
                best_move = move
                best_score = score

    bestest_move = best_move

except Timeout:
    pass

move(bestest_move)
```